How do I find the MAC address of my Synology NAS?
I could not find the MAC address for my Synology NAS; how do I find it?
I searched for this in the control panel network and network bond.

It's probably on a label on the back of the NAS - mine is.

It will be on the same physical label as the serial number, probably on the bottom or back of the enclosure.

Might depend on the OS of your Synology...
All 3 of my Synologies (DSM 7.1.1-42962 Update 7, DSM 7.2.2-72806 Update 2) show all MACs (one for each port) under
Control-Center -> Info-Center -> Network

For your question and other tasks you may want to use Synology Assistant as a desktop utility that searches for Synology servers within the local area network. It allows you to search and connect to your Synology server or set up Wake on LAN (WOL).
If already installed on Windows, type “Synology Assistant” into the taskbar search box and start the application. You'll find the MAC address in the app window.
If not installed:

Go to the Synology Download
Center
Select the product category and the corresponding model you have in use.
Select the OS Version for your needs (if required)
Go to tab Desktop Utilities
Donwload Synology Assistant and install

As mentioned in comments by others you'll find the MAC Address on a label on the back of the NAS. For sample image see e.g. WikiPedia MAC address.

You can find the MAC address by any client machine (in the same network) knowing the hostname (if it is resolved by DNS) or IP of the NAS.
You can use ping and arp commands to get it:
ping <ip_of_NAS>; arp -a

or you can use command like
arping <ip_of_NAS>

First command in form:
ping <ip_of_NAS>
arp -a

work also in Windows
